# Entity Framework Many to Many Database Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am building ASP MVC web site using Entity Framework 4.4 with .NET Framework 4.0

I've add to my model a many to many relation like so:

```
  public class User {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
  }


  public class Tenant {
    public string TenantID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
  }
```

When I run `Add-Migration` command I get this migration class (I remove the Down method)

```
  public partial class TenantUsersManyToManyMigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserTenants",
                c => new
                    {
                        User_UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Tenant_TenantID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.User_UserID, t.Tenant_TenantID })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_UserID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Tenants", t => t.Tenant_TenantID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.User_UserID)
                .Index(t => t.Tenant_TenantID);
        }
  }
```

1. Why are the field names for TenantID and UserID are User_UserID and Tenant_TenantID and not UserID and TenantID, respectively.
2. How can I change the default migration scaffolding (or my model) to make cascadeDelete to be false? (currently I simply change it by hand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the cascade delete convention this way:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```

And then see if the scaffolding changes. I've personally never used it.

Also, Microsoft (kind of) explains the FK naming conventions in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx) under the header `Foreign Keys`.

Comment: Thank you, that answer the second question.

Comment: What clarity were you looking for on your first question? In the link provided it's explained the precedence is given to `<navigation property name><primary key property name>` when deciding FK names.

Comment: this naming convention happen only on many to many. When I map one to many I got just EntityID field name without the navigation property name

Answer (score 7):

You can create your mapping table the way you're wanting using fluent notation.  In your DbContext class, override the OnModelCreating with this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Tenants)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("UserTenants");
                    m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    m.MapRightKey("TenantId");
                });
    }
```

Also, using fluent, if you want to disable cascade deleting on individual tables, you can use the .WillCascadeDelete(false) when mapping properties.  Here's a great [post on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on how to use fluent notations.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure yet how smart it is to mix code first conventions with fluent calls but it sure looks like the way to go until Microsoft will allow to add different conventions and not just removing them